# CSS right sidebar overlaps page content on browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I know this question has been asked plentiful of times, but from all the solutions I found, none of them has worked so far.

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 with a fixed left sidebar, single column row page content and a fixed right sidebar. The left sidebar works as intended but the right sidebar doesn't comply with the page's min-width setting and thus overlaps the page content (screenshots inc).

I want it so that the minimum width for the page is 1024px and content should not resize and the right sidebar should not overlap the content if the browser is smaller than 1024px.

I'm not worried about the responsive design at the moment as there will be a different layout for smaller screen devices.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thanks!

**Before Browser Resize >1024px:**
[image: Before browser resize]
**After Browser Resize <1024px:**
[image: After browser resize]

**CSS Code:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px !important;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 1024px;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -70px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 350px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -75px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: #393839;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 970px;
}
.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 75px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#whobar-wrapper {
  margin-right: -350px;
  right: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background: #393839;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.whobar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-profile" title="My Profile"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-contacts" title="Contacts"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-shortlist" title="Shortlist"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-explore" title="Explore"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="whobar-wrapper">
    <!--    <ul class="whobar-nav">-->
    <!--        <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-profile" title="My Profile"></a></li>-->
    <!--        <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-contacts" title="Contacts"></a></li>-->
    <!--        <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-shortlist" title="Shortlist"></a></li>-->
    <!--        <li><a href="#" class="sidebar_sheet sidebar_sheet-explore" title="Explore"></a></li>-->
    <!--    </ul>-->
  </div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <h1>Temporary Dashboard Header</h1>
          <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
            est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
            sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt
            quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found in your css code are fixed width which actually it wont flex when resizing the screen. My idea of three columns responsive design is try to change the px to % for fluid columns or try to use @media queries

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
         .........
}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I used the @media query to shrink the sidebar when the browser was smaller than a certain width. I am planning to make it collapse/expandable with a button.